# How do I check if a cell with a number equals to the day on a date on other cell?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

Basically, I'm doing a calendar with school assignments with dates.

I made a mini calendar on the left side (one day for each cell) and on the right side I have a list of assignments and the corresponding delivery dates.

I wanted to, each time I add a date to that list, the corresponding day on the mini calendar gets color-filled with Conditional Formatting. How do I do that?

Printscreen
[image: Printscreen]

Comment: I'm using Google Spreadsheet, and I don't think that I asked a "don't ask" question

Comment: Thanks then! I know, but the English community is more active. No I just want to Spreadsheet to fill the days that I have to deliver an assignmente with just one colour, so I'm not adding double digits or anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please clear formatting from and select A6:G10, Format - Conditional formatting..., Custom formula is and:

```
=match(date(2018,3,A6),$I:$I,0)
```

Select formatting of choice and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

I have assumed:

a) when days of the week cause numbers to 'head' for outside the range they will be wrapped back to the start of the range.

b) you will replace `2018` and `3` to the relevant year/month, preferably via cell references.

c) Your dates are true date indices.